# jQuery append datepicker event to other inputs changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to "stack" several on change events for various inputs types, they were working so far until I tried to apply the same on inputs which are of type "input" but are jQuery datepickers:

```
   <div class="col-md-5">
          <input type="input" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="start_date" placeholder="Data (início)" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-5">
          <input type="input" name="end_date" id="end_date" class="end_date" placeholder="Data (fim)" />
   </div>
```

The problem is that the event on change is not triggered when I change the date:

```
            var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
            var $numbers = $('input[type="number"]');
            var $inputs = $('input[type="inputs"]');

            $filterCheckboxes.add($orderBy).add($inputs).add($numbers).on('change', function() {
```

How can I add the datepicker on change or onselect event to the stack?

Comment: It would be useful to include your full script including where you call `.datepicker();`

Answer (score 0):

- Try [refreshing](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh) the datepicker at the end of your onchange function.

In this case, I suggest you to identify inputs which have a datepicker with an additional class or something... In the example, I assume your datepicker inputs has a class named "datepickered".

```
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
var $numbers = $('input[type="number"]');
var $inputs = $('input[type="inputs"]');

$filterCheckboxes.add($orderBy).add($inputs).add($numbers).on('change', function() {
    // [...] Whaterver the function do
    if($(this).hasClass('datepickered')) {
        $(this).datepicker('refresh');
    }
});
```

- Try to bind your function to the [value selection](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) inside the datepicker.

I like more this one: just prevent your event to be added to inputs with datepicker, and then use your function properly like this

```
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
var $numbers = $('input[type="number"]');
var $inputs = $('input[type="inputs"]');
var onChange = function() { /* [...] Whaterver the function do */ };

$filterCheckboxes.add($orderBy).add($inputs).add($numbers).not('.datepickered').on('change', onChange);

$('.datepickered').datepicker({ onSelect: onChange });
```

N.B. I didn't test any part of this code

Comment: How would the refresh option work ? can you elaborate ?

Comment: @DuarteAndrade I have updated my answer, look if it fits your needs, otherwise try to post more of your code